# Regular expression search avoid nested results

Tags: regex, atom-editor

My document contains several instance of code blocks looking like:

```
{% highlight %}
//some code
{% endhighlight %}
```

In Atom.io, I am trying to write a regex search to capture those.

My first try was:
`{% highlight .* %}([\S\s]+){% endhighlight %}`

The problem is because there are several code blocks in the same document, it also catches the first code block until the last one, all in one match.

I though to exclude the `{` character:
`{% highlight .* %}([^\{]+){% endhighlight %}`

But the problem is that some of the code blocks contain valid `{` characters (such as `function(){ ... }`).

Comment: Are there any nested blocks?

Comment: If you mean, can there be a `highlight` within another `highlight` then the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

Use non greedy matching:

```
{% highlight .* %}([\S\s]+?){% endhighlight %}
                          ^
```

Comment: I would not recommend it, the blocks may be very long and the lazy matching might cause issues then. Also, it does not deal with nested blocks (not yet confirmed by OP).

Comment: That seems to do the job! Can you explain?

Comment: @stribizhev maybe write it in an answer?

Comment: @NathanH `+` will match as many characters as possible.. adding a `?` after `+` will make it lazy and match as less as possible.

Comment: @karthikmanchala did you do a benchmark? Try it, the other solution seems to be by far of better performance but because of simplicity of a maybe onetime task upvoted both your solutions. The overhead in writing the other pattern might be more time consuming.

Comment: @karthikmanchala: I do not say your regex is wrong, I just want to say that in case the blocks of text are large/huge, my solution should cope with them in a faster and safer way.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with Karthik's lazy matching solution is that when you have large substrings between `{% highlight %}` and `{% end highlight %}` the `[\s\S]*?` will be storing more and more text into the backtracking buffer that can eventually overrun.

Using an [*unrolling-the-loop*](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) technique, you can avoid that:

```
{% highlight %}([^{]*(?:{(?!% endhighlight %})[^{]*)*){% endhighlight %}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fX4bV7/2)

This way, the substrings inside the highlight blocks can be of any length and performance will stay fast.

Main regex parts:

- `{% highlight %}` - matches the `{% highlight %}` text literally
- `([^{]*(?:{(?!% endhighlight %})[^{]*)*)` - matches and captures into group 1 everything that is not `{% endhighlight %}` matching:

  - `[^{]*` - 0 or more characters other than `{`
  - `(?:{(?!% endhighlight %})[^{]*)*` - 0 or more sequences of....

    - `{(?!% endhighlight %})` - literal `{` not followed by `% endhighlight %}`
    - `[^{]*` - 0 or more characters other than `{`
- `{% endhighlight %}` - matches the `{% endhighlight %}` text literally

This is basically the same as `{% highlight %}([\s\S]*?){% endhighlight %}`, but "unwraped". The linear execution ensures safer and faster user experience.

Comment: I dont see how performance will stay.. because lookaheads will compromise on number of matches...

Comment: If I wanted to capture the code block inside, what would I do?

Comment: @NathanH what language are you using?

Comment: None, this is inside the Atom text editor. But I see your regex already captures the content.

Comment: @karthikmanchala: Welcome back to SO, I have not seen you for ages. Compare your regex and mine, and type more and more text in between the "tags", and you will see the number of steps growing when using your lazy quantifier based solution. My regex is linear, thus, the look-ahead is not a problem. Lazy matching is a problem with large texts and here, performance seems to be something to account for.

Comment: It's not really a storing problem (but it may be, depending of what follows the non-greedy quantifier). What makes a non-greedy quantifier slow is that before taking each character, the end of the pattern must be tested until it fails. There's no risk of overflow.

Comment: @NathanH: I agree my wording can be corrected (**everyone who is pedantic about wording please feel free to correct**), sure, but when `b[\s\S]*?c` causes your code crash, just remember to come back and try my solution.

Comment: @stribizhev glad that you remember :) I just confirmed and I think you are right for huge texts..

Answer (score -2):

This regex you can get only content in `{% highlight %} ... {% endhighlight %}`:

`(?<={% highlight %}).*(?={% endhighlight %})`

Test:
https://regex101.com/r/nX6wV8/1

---

Sorry for my fail, I hope this can help you

New expression:
https://regex101.com/r/qX2cA1/1

Comment: Even if using lookarounds avoids to create a capture group, it doesn't solve the original problem: https://regex101.com/r/nX6wV8/2

Comment: @Lai32290: This regex [does not match several blocks](https://regex101.com/r/nX6wV8/3) and can be difficult to use in case the `/s` singleline modifier is not supported by Atom.