# Regex matching across single and multiple lines

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace

Lets say I am using Visual Studio's Find and Replace tool and I want to find and comment out every instance of `Console.WriteLine(...)`. However, I can wind up with situations where `Console.WriteLine(...)` goes across multiple lines like so:

```
Console.WriteLine("Adding drive to VM with ID: {0}. Drive HostVMID is {1}",
     vm.ID, drive.HostVmId);
```

These can go on for 2, 3, 4, etc lines and finally end with `);` to close the statement. Then I can have other lines that are immediately followed by important blocks of code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Creating snapshot for VM: {0} {1}", dbVm.ID, dbVm.VmName);
dbContext.Add(new RTVirtualMachineSnapshot(dbVm));
```

So what I want to do is come up with a regex statement that will find both the first type of instances of `Console.WriteLine` as well as simple single-line instances of it.

The Regex that I got from another user was:

```
Console\.writeline(?>.+)(?<!;)
```

Which will match any line that contains `Console.WriteLine` but does **not** end with a semicolon. However I need it to *continue* on until it finally **does** reach a closing parenthesis followed by a semicolon.

Ive tried the following regex:

```
(Console\.writeline(?>.+)(?<!\);)
```

However I think thats incorrect because it still only matches the first line and doesnt capture the following lines when the writeline spans multiple lines.

At the end of the day I want to be able to capture a **full** Console.writeline statement regardless of how many lines it spans using Visual Studio's find and replace feature and I am a little confused on the regex I would need to use to do this.

Comment: Why did you post a new question? I could update my answer at the [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34185524/net-regex-negative-lookahead-when-looking-for-semicolons/34185663?noredirect=1#comment56117740_34185663).

Comment: So, what do we do? Close this one as a duplicate or moving the update here?

Comment: Which VS are you using ? Greater or equal to 12 ?

Comment: In general, you're not going to be able to parse _all_ the parameters that can be passed to functions. If it's a one-off thing, use the best regex you can and manually find next until you find one you want to replace, then hit replace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Regex negative lookahead when looking for semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34185524/net-regex-negative-lookahead-when-looking-for-semicolons)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try this which just looks for a pseudo termination,
but does not take into account string quotes.

`(?s)\b(Console\s*\.\s*WriteLine\s*\((?:(?!\)\s*;).)*\)\s*;)`

Formatted:

```
 (?s)
 \b
 (                             # (1 start)
      Console \s* \. \s* WriteLine \s* \(
      (?:
           (?! \) \s* ; )
           . 
      )*
      \) \s* ;
 )                             # (1 end)
```

**add:**

If you cannot use dot-all modifier `(?s)` and Dot-all options are not available (should be),
substitute `[\S\s]` for the dot.

Then just substitute `"/** $1 **/"` to comment it out.